# Navigating to google maps Call Back

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, callback

Im using Google maps to navigate. As per Documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/urlscheme), I Used Call back scheme.But there is no button on top of google maps to come back to my app.

There is once small button to go back to my app (which is Avaialble in IOS 9) on top left with my app name.

So Where this scheme(comgooglemaps-x-callback://) will add the button to come back to my app?

Also I didn't feel any difference between "comgooglemaps-x-callback://" and "comgooglemaps://".

Please help me...

Thank You...

Comment: back button is OS feature.

Comment: Yes. Then whats the difference between those 2 schemes provide by google

Answer (score 0):

According to google

**comgooglemaps:// and comgooglemaps-x-callback://** -

> These schemes allow you to launch the Google Maps app for iOS and
>   perform one of several actions:
>
> Display a map at a specified location and zoom level. Search for
>   locations or places, and display them on a map. Request directions
>   from one location to another. Directions can be returned for four
>   modes of transportation: driving, walking, bicycling and public
>   transit. Add navigation to your app. Through iOS 8, issue a callback
>   when the app has completed, using

**comgooglemaps-x-callback://**.

> Callbacks are often used to return a user to the app that originally
>   opened Google Maps for iOS. Note that on iOS 9, the system
>   automatically provides a "Back to" link in left corner of the status
>   bar. comgooglemapsurl:// -
>
> This scheme allows you to launch the Google Maps app for iOS using a
>   URL derived from the desktop Google Maps website. This means that you
>   can give your users a native mobile experience rather than simply
>   loading the Google Maps website.
>
> The original URL can be for maps.google.com, or for google.com/maps,
>   or using any valid top-level country domain instead of com. You can
>   also pass on goo.gl/maps redirection URLs. You can issue a callback
>   using the x-source and x-success parameters with the
>   comgooglemapsurl:// URL scheme.

Comment: When the Call Back will Happen?

Comment: There must be a back button on top left

Comment: Yes. Its Provided By OS, Even though I'm not using "comgooglemaps-x-callback://." . Im getting that back button